# How can we know the total number of elements of Array?

Tags: arrays

```
sizeof($array_var)
count($array_var)
```

If we just pass a simple var instead of a an array it will return 1.

Comment: Is this a particular language?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Which language are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof($array_var)`
`count($array_var)`
If we just pass a simple var instead of a an array it will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sizeof](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) PHP function is an alias of [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function, just in place of count use sizeof function. But it is recommended to use count instead of sizeof, anyway, the output will be the same.

```
<?php
    $a[0] = 1;
    $a[1] = 3;
    $a[2] = 5;
    $result = count($a);
    // $result == 3
?>


<?php
    $a[0] = 1;
    $a[1] = 3;
    $a[2] = 5;
    $result = sizeof($a);
    // $result == 3
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do what you're asking for is to verify the type of the entry variable:

```
function get_array_size($array_var){
    if(is_array($array_var)){
        return sizeof($array_var);
    }else if(is_string($array_var)){
         return 1;
    }
```